# How to print the correct values input from a .csv file -- JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, csv, file, file-io

When I run the test program it just returns zeros instead of years. I can't figure out why. It seems like the stats are calculating correctly. I need for it to display the years for the range of population growth instead of those zeros. And for the years for minimum and maximum for the specific crimes. Here is the code so far (3 Files):

```
/**
* File: USCrimeClass.java
* Author: Noah Smith
* Date: 11/16/2020
* Purpose: To create a class to parse crime data
*/
public class USCrimeClass {

    // Crime data fields for each data to retrieve
    private int year;
    private double populationGrowth;
    private int maxMurderYear;
    private int minMurderYear;
    private int maxRobberyYear;
    private int minRobberyYear;
    
    //Crime data constructor to set variables
    public USCrimeClass(int year, int populationGrowth, int maxMurderYear, int minMurderYear, int maxRobberyYear, int minRobberyYear){
        this.year = year;
        this.populationGrowth = populationGrowth;
        this.maxMurderYear = maxMurderYear;
        this.minMurderYear = minMurderYear;
        this.maxRobberyYear = maxRobberyYear;
        this.minRobberyYear = minRobberyYear;
    }

    // Constructor defaults
    public USCrimeClass(int i){
        this.year = 0;
        this.populationGrowth = 0.0;
        this.maxMurderYear = 0;
        this.minMurderYear = 0;
        this.maxRobberyYear = 0;
        this.minRobberyYear = 0;
    }

    //Getter methods for each field
    public int getYear() {return this.year; }
    public double getPopulationGrowth() {return this.populationGrowth; }
    public int getMaxMurderYear() {return this.maxMurderYear; }
    public int getMinMurderYear() {return this.minMurderYear; }
    public int getMaxRobberyYear() {return this.maxRobberyYear; }
    public int getMinRobberyYear() {return this.minRobberyYear; }

    // Setter method for each field
    public void setYear(int year) {this.year = year;}
    public void setPopulationGrowth(double populationGrowth) {this.populationGrowth = populationGrowth;}
    public void setMaxMurderYear(int maxMurders) {this.maxMurderYear = maxMurders;}
    public void setMinMurderYear(int minMurders) {this.minMurderYear = minMurders;}
    public void setMaxRobberyYear(int maxRobbery) {this.maxRobberyYear = maxRobbery;}
    public void setMinRobberyYear(int minRobbery) {this.minRobberyYear = minRobbery;}
}

/**
* File: USCrimeFile.java
* Author: Noah Smith
* Date: 11/16/2020
* Purpose: Access Crime.csv and create methods to calculate stats
*
*/

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class USCrimeFile {

    public static USCrimeClass[] read(String filename){

        // Array declaration
        USCrimeClass[] stats = new USCrimeClass[20];
        Scanner inputReader = null;
        // Variable declaration
        int count = 0;
        String line;
        // Access Crime.csv and create array
        try{
            inputReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            // Read first line
            inputReader.nextLine();
            while (inputReader.hasNext()) {
                line = inputReader.nextLine();
                String[] data = line.split(",");
                stats[count] = new USCrimeClass(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
                stats[count].setPopulationGrowth(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                stats[count].setMaxMurderYear(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                stats[count].setMinMurderYear(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                stats[count].setMaxRobberyYear(Integer.parseInt(data[8]));
                stats[count].setMinRobberyYear(Integer.parseInt(data[8]));
                count++;
            }

            return stats;
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        finally {
            inputReader.close();
        }

    }

    // Method calculation for population growth rate
    public void populationGrowth(USCrimeClass[] data){
        double growthRate;
        System.out.println("Population growth rate: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++){
            growthRate = 100 * (float) (data[i+1].getPopulationGrowth() - data[i].getPopulationGrowth()) / data[i].getPopulationGrowth();
            System.out.println("From " + data[i].getYear() + " to " + data[i + 1].getYear() + " the population growth was "+ String.format("%.4f", growthRate) + "%");
        }
    }

    // Method to find year with highest murder rate
    public String maxMurderYear(USCrimeClass[] data) {
        int iSize = data.length;
        double currentMurderRate = 0.00;
        double mMurderRate;
        int murderHighYear = 0;
        String stReturnValue;
        // Access array
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {

            // Get murder rate
            mMurderRate = data[i].getMaxMurderYear();
            if (mMurderRate < currentMurderRate) {
            murderHighYear = data[i].getYear();
            }
            currentMurderRate = mMurderRate;
            }
            stReturnValue = "The murder rate was highest in " + murderHighYear + ".";
            return stReturnValue;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Method to find lowest murder year
    public String minMurderYear(USCrimeClass[] data) {
        int iSize = data.length;
        double currentMurderRate = 0.00;
        double mMurderRate;
        int murderLowYear = 0;
        String stReturnValue;
        try {
            // Access array
            for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
                // Get the murder rate
                mMurderRate = data[i].getMinMurderYear();
                if (mMurderRate > currentMurderRate) {
                murderLowYear = data[i].getYear();
                }
                currentMurderRate = mMurderRate;
            }
            stReturnValue = "The murder rate was lowest in " + murderLowYear + ".";
            return stReturnValue;
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Get the year with highest robberies
    public String maxRobberyYear(USCrimeClass[] data) {
        int iSize = data.length;
        double currentRobberyRate = 0.00;
        double dRobberyRate;
        int robberyHighYear = 0;
        String stReturnValue;
        // Access array
        try {
        for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
            // Get the robbery rate
            dRobberyRate = data[i].getMaxRobberyYear();
            if (dRobberyRate < currentRobberyRate) {
                robberyHighYear = data[i].getYear();
            }
            currentRobberyRate = dRobberyRate;
        }
        stReturnValue = "The robbery rate was highest in " + robberyHighYear + ".";
        return stReturnValue;
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Method to find lowest robbery year
    public String minRobberyYear(USCrimeClass[] data) {
        int iSize = data.length;
        double currentRobberyRate = 0.00;
        double dRobberyRate;
        int robberyLowYear = 0;
        String stReturnValue;
        // Access array
        try {
        for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
            // Get robbery rate
            dRobberyRate = data[i].getMinRobberyYear();
            if (dRobberyRate > currentRobberyRate) {
                robberyLowYear = data[i].getYear();
            }
            currentRobberyRate = dRobberyRate;
            }
            stReturnValue = "The robbery rate was lowest in " + robberyLowYear + ".";
            return stReturnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}

/**
* File: TestUSCrime.java
* Author: Noah Smith
* Date: 11/16/2020
* Purpose:
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestUSCrime {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Reference USCrimeFile
        USCrimeFile oUSCrimeFile = new USCrimeFile();
        USCrimeClass[] data = USCrimeFile.read("Crime.csv");

        //Declare variables
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime;
        String userSelect;
        while (true) {
            // Welcome prompt
            System.out.println("******** Welcome to the US Crime Statistical Application********\n");
            System.out.println("\n" + "Enter the number of the question you want answered. Enter 'Q' to quit the program:\n");
            System.out.println("1. What were the percentages in population growth for each consecutive year from 1994-2013?");
            System.out.println("2. What year was the murder rate the highest?");
            System.out.println("3. What year wat the murder rate the lowest?");
            System.out.println("4. What year was the robbery rate the highest?");
            System.out.println("5. What year was the robbery rate the lowest?");
            System.out.println("Q. Quit the program");
            System.out.println("\nEnter your selection: ");
            userSelect = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            switch (userSelect){
                
                case "1":
                oUSCrimeFile.populationGrowth(data);
                break;
                case "2":
                System.out.println("The murder rate was highest in " + oUSCrimeFile.maxMurderYear(data));
                break;
                case "3":
                System.out.println("The murder rate was lowest in " + oUSCrimeFile.minMurderYear(data));
                break;
                case "4":
                System.out.println("The robbery rate was highest in: " + oUSCrimeFile.maxRobberyYear(data));
                break;
                case "5":
                System.out.println("The robbery rate was highest in: " + oUSCrimeFile.minRobberyYear(data));
                break;
                case "Q":
                System.out.println("\nThank you for trying the US Crime Statistics Program");
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("\nElapsed time in seconds was: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + "seconds.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 99% sure it has to do with the getYear() method

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a setter for the year. That solved this issue, however some other issues came up that had to do with data types which I late solved.

```
    while (inputReader.hasNext()) {
                    line = inputReader.nextLine();
                    String[] data = line.split(",");
                    stats[count] = new USCrimeClass(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
                    stats[count].setPopulationGrowth(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                    stats[count].setYear(Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
                    stats[count].setMaxMurderYear(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                    stats[count].setMinMurderYear(Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                    stats[count].setMaxRobberyYear(Integer.parseInt(data[8]));
                    stats[count].setMinRobberyYear(Integer.parseInt(data[8]));
                    count++;
                }
```